Wordress filter the entire content including the template and structure from body
Wordpress has a hook for filtering the content of a post or page;
add_filter('the_content' fn() => // something);

This filters the post content and allows us to modify it / manipulate the DOM etc..
However, it relates only to the output of $post->post_content and therefore does not allow anything to be manipulated before then. Whilst much of what happens before then can be manipulated from the template there are still two HTML elements Wordpress will add anyway after the opening body tag. The first is a div with class "wp-site-blocks" and the second "entry-content".
Is there a hook or similar that would allow the entire content from the opening body tag to be manipulated at the server level.
Something like:
add_filter('full_post_body_content');


a big part of the html around "post_content" is generated by the theme and can be customise by a child theme. have you a example of modification you want to do ?

Unfortunately there is no filter to modify that part of your pages. The wp-site-blocks div is created in the get_the_block_template_html() function, which is being called by WP internally. And there don't seem to be any hooks either.

If you are doing it from the child theme, you may want to replace the template. for example copy your current - single-post.php (or for custom post type "single-{custom-post-type}.php") and replace those elements, easiest way actually.
Other solution you may try - ob_start() on 'wp_head' them ob_get_clean() in the 'wp_footer'.

Thanks. It won't quite solve it but given that the entire site in this case is then compiled statically every three hours to GIT I'm modifying the scripts that do this instead.
